# Какой знак препинания нужно поставить перед "и это" тире или запятую? Или знака там вообще быть не должно?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, союзы

В тяжелые времена большинство людей концентрируются на негативе, концентрируются на своих проблемах – и это большая ошибка.